# JQuery Addition/subtraction from dynamically added input text

Tags: jquery, input, dynamically-generated, addition, subtraction

I have this scenario: 
I have text input in a form and using them to make some calculations (basically addition and subtraction). Text inputs (sub-total) can be added/removed via jQuery with a onclick. So far i've been able to get the sum (total) of the input elements when i add them to the form and put some values into them. What i'm missing now is the way to update the total sum whenever i remove one text input. Here is the code, I have also a [JSFIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/uomopalese/1w54rhyv/](http://jsfiddle.net/uomopalese/1w54rhyv/). Thanks for help.

CODE: (updated with the solution proposed by [@iovis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4008739/iovis)

```
<div id="dati-dettaglio-linee">
  <div id="righe">
    <div class="linea"><!-- ripetizione linea -->
    <h5>Nr. linea: <span>1</span></h5>
    <ul>
     <li>Sub total: <span><input class="somma" type="text" value="" name="ValoreTotale" /></span></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- ripetizione linea -->
</div><!-- righe -->
<div class="link-button"><a href="javascript:;" id="addButton">ADD LINE</a></div>
<div class="link-button"><a href="javascript:;" id="removeButton">REMOVE LINE</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="riepilogo-aliquote-nature">
  <ul>
    <li>Total: <span class="totale"><input type="text" value="" id="ImponibileImporto" /></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div><!-- dettaglio-linee -->


/////////////////////////////////// ADD LINES 
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
    //alert('Stai per aggiungere una linea di contenuto alla fattura');
    $("#righe").append('<div id="linea' + counter + '"><h5>Nr. linea: <span>' + counter + '</span></h5>' + '\n\r' +
      '<ul>' +'\n\r' +  
      '<li>Sub total: <span><input class="somma" type="text" value="" id="ValoreTotale' + counter + '" /></span></li>' + '\n\r' + 
      '</ul></div>');
counter++;;
$(".somma").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
  });
  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
 //alert('Stai per rimuovere una linea di contenuto alla fattura');
 if(counter==2){
      alert("Non ci sono altre linee da eliminare");
      return false;
   }   
 counter--;
  $("#linea" + counter).remove();
   calculateSum();
  });
 });
/////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////FUNCTION ADD VELUES
$(document).ready(function(){           
  $(".somma").each(function() {
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateSum();
        });
    });
 });
function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".somma").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    //$("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    $('.totale input').val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems you just need to call calculateSum() on the remove event...

```
    $("#removeButton").click(function() {
      if (counter == 2) {
        alert("Non ci sono altre linee da eliminare");
        return false;
      }

      counter--;
      $("#linea" + counter).remove();
      calculateSum(); // <-- Add this
    });
```

Comment: I tried in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uomopalese/1w54rhyv/) and it doesn't work, you can try yourself

Comment: If you just need to get the total updated when you remove an element then it works for me in jsfiddle, did you click "Run" after?

Comment: Sorry [@iovis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4008739/iovis), my fault, your way works well as the others, and was the first, so I accept. Sorry everybody, i made a bit of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
$.when($("#linea" + counter).remove()).then(function(){
    calculateSum();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/1w54rhyv/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You confused with attribites `name` and `id`.

you are accessing input fields using `names` it won't work. we can access them using `class` name or `id`.

I modified fiddle. check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/1w54rhyv/1/)

Comment: Got it! i need the 'name' attribute to send values to php via `$_POST`, but i can use both name and id. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: You are again calculating the sum, i believe that is not the actual problem. Rather i would suggest is to have a callback after remove method and call the calculateSum method.